# SignalR 2 - Reconnect

Tags: .net, signalr

I have Win Forms .net 4.5 SignalR server on Windows 2012. Clients are also win forms applications using .net 4 framework on Windows XP SP3.

Currently I have 400 clients connected and my server have `onReconnect()` event fires more than I expected (every 20-40 sec). My clients have `Connection.EnsureReconnecting();`

My question is : Is this normal behavior of LongPolling transport.

Comment: No. It is not normal.

Comment: This is not a normal behaviour. Can you try switching on Signalr logs for client and server? It will give some idea of what is going with signalr communication.

Comment: I am just starting with SignalR trying to replace my WebService pooling with SignalR pushing ... my clients are live and always on line and I can not allow they stop working so my play ground is very narrow, doing small steps to achieve my goals. In next version I will add some logs so I can see which ones are constantly reconnecting. I assume that 400 connections is not a big deal for SignalR. Than You all for comments.